# How to suppress printing in data.table ( <= 1.9.4) when no rows match selection

Tags: r, data.table

When I use the syntax like `dt[colA=='x'&colB=='y', mycol:=y]` and there are no rows matching the criteria, I get the whole `dt` printed. Is there a way to suppress this output or disable it somehow?

Example:

```
dt = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
dt[x=='j',y:=5] # works fine, nothing is printed
dt[x=='j'&v==10,y:=5] # dt is printed
dt[x=='j'|v==10,y:=5] # dt is printed
```

Comment: It was fixed in the devel version. You can download it from GH using `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` or wait until the next stable realise on cran.

Comment: Thanks! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: I think we can close as no longer reproducible?

Comment: It's a bit ironic when questions get closed (and I have added my close-vote) when the correct answer is update to a non-CRAN package version.

Comment: @BondedDust this question is pretty Off topic here and should be posted on GH in the first place. Also, how can we help if the issue was already fixed? Ask `data.table` devs to update v 1.9.4?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Actually the `data.table` authors/maintainers are a regular participants here and have endorsed using SO as a forum where problems can be posted. It is a question related to the released version of the package. I'm not aware that this particular issue has been duplicated, and now by closing it without an answer we have prevented linking to it if it should be posted again. Problem was documented with code. I would have thought you could have posted the material in your comment as an answer.

Comment: @BondedDust I'm well aware of `data.table` authors/maintainers presence on SO. Though, I don't think that long time fixed bugs should be posted as answers here- but I may be wrong (not sure regarding SO policy too). Either way, this bug was the second bug that was fixed in v 1.9.5, so you can find it documented on the second bullet of **BUG FIXES** [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

Comment: Maybe we should post on MetaSO? I've been acting on the assumption that problems with version mismatches, like a couple I've answered recently on SO and R-help, as well as bug fixes that are not yet released on CRAN would be legitimate topics for discussion. (I'm puzzled that the push to CRAN for version 1.9.5 has been delayed so long. Earlier questions _and_ accepted answers have appeared earlier.)

Comment: I believe this Meta q/a supports my posture: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/how-to-deal-with-this-is-fixed-in-x-and-this-is-a-bug-answers/251721#251721

Comment: @BondedDust Another fellow close-voter here. I agree. "long time fixed" doesn't really describe bugs fixed off CRAN in my opinion; and I think it's still a valid question even if it's only a problem because the user is on a one year-old version of R. I just salvaged my own question by putting the affected versions of R ( <= 3.2.0) in the title. A convention like that would be fine, I think.

Comment: Agree with BondedDust. Voted to reopen. Much better to provide an answer and link back to this on future Q.

Comment: An answer to put here could be "wrapping inside `invisible(..)` could help you on DT <= 1.9.4" to avoid answering with previously mentioned supposedly unorthodox "update to a non-CRAN package version".